# Ruby Test Unit: Multiple Scripts, One Output

Tags: ruby, testunit

Can I run multiple Test Cases from multiple scripts but have a single output that either says "100% Pass" or "X Failed" and lists out the failed tests?

For example I want to see something like:

```
>runtests.rb all #runs all the scripts in the directory
Finished in 4.523 Seconds
100% Pass

>runtests.rb category #runs all the scripts in a specified sub-directory
Finished in 2.1 Seconds
2 Failed:
test_my_test
test_my_test_2
1 Error:
test_my_test_3
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the built-in [MiniTest::Unit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/index.html) along with the `autotest` command that is part of [ZenTest](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ZenTest/frames) and get output like:

```
autotest
/Users/tinman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit tests/test_domains.rb tests/test_regex.rb tests/test_vlan.rb tests/test_nexus.rb tests/test_switch.rb tests/test_template.rb].each { |f| require f }"
Loaded suite -e
Started
........................................
Finished in 0.143375 seconds.

40 tests, 276 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 62474
```

Is that similar to what you are talking about?